# How to get the previous value for a solidjs signal?

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I want to get the previous value of a signal how?

```
const [route, setRoute] = createSignal(1)

createEffect(() => {
  console.log('route previous value is', route(0))
  console.log('route updated value is', route())
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function you provide to `createEffect` can take an argument than is equal to the returned value from the effect function's last call. Therefore, you can do the following:

```js
const [route, setRoute] = createSignal(1);

createEffect((prev) => {
  const updated = route();

  console.log('route previous value is', prev);
  console.log('route updated value is', updated);

  return updated;
}, route());
```

Note that the second argument you pass to `createEffect` is the initial value for `prev`.

This described in the [createEffect section of the Solid API docs](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#createeffect).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the previous signal value to compute a new one, you can pass a function to the signal setter function that receives the previous value as the argument.

```js
const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0)

// The setter also returns the updated value.
const newCount = setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
```

Source: [`createSignal` API reference](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createsignal)